# Common api to develope for Quick books online and offile integration

Tags: quickbooks, quickbooks-online

some of our customers have Quick book online and some of our customers have quick book offline. i want to develop Quick book integration for both in common way.  is there any api there to develop integration for both in common

Comment: Why add a 2nd question to this question?? Why didn't you just ask another?

Comment: @paul: thanks for correcting me. i removed the 2nd question and asked as a new question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Already answered your question over here:
[Intuit Developer Forums](https://idnforums.intuit.com/messageview.aspx?catid=56&threadid=17478&enterthread=y)

Use IPP (Intuit Partner Platform)/IDS (Intuit Data Services).

The APIs for each are very, very similar, but not identical. It basically involves HTTP POSTing data to Intuit's servers. The data is then either relayed directly into QuickBooks Online, or held for later syncing against QuickBooks desktop versions (by default, Intuit handles the sync against QuickBooks desktop every 5 minutes).

Authentication against Intuit's servers is via OAuth, or via SAML (OAuth is easy, and the encouraged method of integration).

Documentation for that is here:
[Intuit Partner Platform documentation](https://ipp.developer.intuit.com/0010_Intuit_Partner_Platform)

Note that as of April 2012, the Intuit Partner Platform APIs are only available to SaaS applications (i.e. if you're developing a one-off/custom application that you're not going to resell, then you can't use this set of APIs- in that case look at the Web Connector/SDK instead).

If you're using PHP, grab a nightly build of the PHP DevKit here for example code and libraries: 
[QuickBooks PHP DevKit](http://consolibyte.com/quickbooks-open-source/)

Comment: Hi keith, i added new problem in my question. can you guide me to overcome the problem

Comment: If you have a NEW question, then you should create a NEW question. Mark this question as answered, and create a new question, and I will answer it there.

Comment: i have deleted the 2 question and asked as a new question

Answer (score 2):

Additional info:

Intuit Data Services v2 has two separate but similar services one for QuickBooks Online and One for QuickBooks for Windows.

Intuit has released 2 SDKs one in Java and one in .Net which make programming against both easier. There is a common model for data that exists in both, and then you can extend to use data in Online or Desktop if needed.

[.Net SDK for Intuit Data Services 2.0](https://ipp.developer.intuit.com/0010_Intuit_Partner_Platform/0200_DevKits_for_Intuit_Partner_Platform/0100_IPP_.NET_DevKit) 
[Java SDK for Intuit Data Services 2.0](https://ipp.developer.intuit.com/0010_Intuit_Partner_Platform/0200_DevKits_for_Intuit_Partner_Platform/0200_IPP_Java_DevKit)

Next: Intuit Data Services v3 (One service to rule them all)
v3 brings QuicKBooks Online and QB for Windows under one service.
As with v2 Intuit will also provide java and .Net SDK support for the Service.